# build automation windows store apps

Tags: msbuild, windows-store-apps, build-automation, windows-store

I'm want to create automated build environment for windows store apps (phone/tablet) & after creating build provide way(link to download) to deploy it on devices. Right now packages for testing needs to manually installed on device and then hand over for QA or upload on Windows beta store for phone apps. 
Would like to know what possible tools can be used to serve this purpose. Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: hockey app might help http://hockeyapp.net/features/distribution/

Comment: Successfully tried: [OrgPortal](https://github.com/magenic/orgportal). Haven't tried: [CompanyStore](http://companystore.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @TomBlodget Good leads, I'll explore more about it!